# Post back values using Perl and jQuery

Tags: jquery, perl

I am trying to use in one script, that once this form gets submitted, it will update the database and post back the results to it-self, on the same page without the page refreshing . 
I am stuck trying to understand why once the form gets submitted and all the values get passed ( I can see all the values using firebug ) the results doesn’t show on the page like in this line:

```
 print "<br>Display Results once the submit gets done: *$user_name*$user_id*$city_from*$state_from*$checkin_comments*<br>";
```

What am I missing.
I have this test code that shows what I am trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $q = CGI->new();

print $q->header();

my $transac = $q->param( 'transac' ) || '';

# Get values

my $user_name        = $q->param( 'user_name' )        || '';
my $user_id          = $q->param( 'userid' )           || '';
my $city_from        = $q->param( 'city_from' )        || '';
my $state_from       = $q->param( 'state_from' )       || '';
my $checkin_comments = $q->param( 'checkin_comments' ) || '';

print "<br>Display Results once the submit gets done: *$user_name*$user_id*$city_from*$state_from*$checkin_comments*<br>";



if($transac eq "checkin") {

  my $res = results();
  print "<br> *$res* $user_name*$user_id*$city_from*$state_from*$checkin_comments*<br>";

}else {

start_html();

}

sub results {

  if ($user_name) {

  return 'success';

  } else {

   return 'error';

  }

 } # End sub results


sub start_html {

 my $html_code = qq (
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="en-gb" />
 <title>jquery from hell</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

   \$(function () {

    \$('.reply-comment').on('click', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var form = \$('.reply-form');

    var CommentID = \$(this).attr('id');

    //alert(CommentID);

    if (form.is(':visible')) {

    // hide it
    form.hide(function () {

      \$('#' + CommentID).html('<a href="" class="reply-comment" id="reply-comment-' + CommentID + '"> [ Check-In ] </a>');

    });

    }else{

    // show it
    form.show(function () {

            \$('#' + CommentID).html('<a href="" class="reply-comment" id="reply-comment-' + CommentID + '">[ Cancel ]</a>');

     });

    }

    });

   });

 </script>
<style>

  .reply-form {

         display:none;           
   }

 </style>

 <script type="text/javascript" >

  function onSuccess(data, status) {

    data = \$.trim(data);

     alert(data);

     var form = \$('.reply-form');
     var CommentID = 1;

    \$("form#reply-form").trigger('reset');

    if (data) {

    // hide it
    form.hide(function () {

      \$('#' + CommentID).html('<a href="" class="reply-comment" id="reply-comment-' + CommentID + '"> [ xCheck-In ] </a>');

    });

    }else{

    // show it
    form.show(function () {

            \$('#' + CommentID).html('<a href="" class="reply-comment" id="reply-comment-' + CommentID + '">[ xCancel ]</a>');

     });

   }
  }

  function onError(data, status, e) {

   alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
   alert(data);
   console.log(e);

  }  

  \$(document).ready(function(){

  \$("form#reply-form").submit(function() { // reply-form is submitted

  var formData = \$("#reply-form").serialize();
 // alert(formData);

 \$.ajax({

   type: "post",
   url: "pjtest.pl",
   cache: false,
   data: formData,
   success: onSuccess,
   error:   onError

  });

 // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
 return false;

 });

 });

</script>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<table width="500" border="1" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
               <tr>
                   <form name="postItem" action="test.pl" method="post" STYLE="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">

                 <td align="center" width="33%" valign="bottom">
                   <input type="submit" id="submitLink" value="[ Post ]">
                 </td></form>

                 <td align="center" width="34%" valign="middle">
                   <a href="" class="reply-comment" id="1"> [ Check-In ] </a>
                 </td>

                   <form name="postItem" action="test.pl" method="post" STYLE="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">

                 <td align="right" width="33%" valign="bottom">
                    <input type="submit" id="submitLink" value="[ Log out ]">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                 </td>
                  </form>
               </tr>
              </table>
              <!-- Check in stuff -->
              <div class="reply-form well">

              <table width="100%" border="0" bgcolor="#1A1A1A" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
               <tr><form name="reply-form" id="reply-form" method="post" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                       <input id="transac" type="hidden" name="transac" value="checkin">
                       <input id="user_name" type="hidden" name="user_name" value="theusername">
                       <input id="userid" type="hidden" name="userid" value="923">
                       <input id="city"  name="city_from" type="hidden" value="Boston" />
                       <input id="state" name="state_from" type="hidden" value="MA" />
                 <td align="center">
                       <textarea id="checkin_comments" name="checkin_comments" rows="4"  cols="40" class="span10"></textarea>
                 </td>
               <tr>
                 <td align="center">
                       <!--input type="submit" id="submitLink" value="[ Submit ]" /-->
                       <input type="image" src="/images/check.png" alt="Submit button" width="50" height="33" class="submit" id="send_comments">
                     </form>

                   </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
</body></html>);

print $html_code;

#return $html_code;

 } # End start_html sub
```

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1069010

Comment: The perlmonks.org comments only recommended cosmetics changes to the code, not any answer to the issue here posted. Unfortunately.

Comment: toolic's point was that you cross-posted to PerlMonks without saying so in your question. Cross-posting is fine but it's generally considered polite to tell people that you're doing so. Also, as soon as you get an answer on either site, please update the other one so people don't waste their time finding a solution to a problem that has already been solved.

Comment: Also, you're unlikely to get many answers when you post a huge wall of code like that; it's a lot for people to wade through. Try to narrow down the issue to a short, self-contained example to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Yes, I would do that of course!

Answer (score 0):

I did that:

```
my $state_from       = $q->param( 'state_from' )       || '';
my $checkin_comments = $q->param( 'checkin_comments' ) || '';
# print "<br>Display Results once the submit gets done:   *$user_name*$user_id*$city_from*$state_from*$checkin_comments*<br>";
```

and that:

```
if (data) {

   // hide it
  form.hide(function () {

  \$('#' + CommentID).html('<a href="" class="reply-comment" id="reply-comment-' + CommentID + '"> [ xCheck-In ] </a>');

  });
  \$('#results').html(data);
```

and finally that:

```
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<br>Display Results once the submit gets done: <span id='results'></span><br>
<table width="500" border="1" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
```

and got text like that:

Display Results once the submit gets done:
*success* theusername*923*Boston*MA*asd*